# Seeing the Chicago Board of Trade

Tags: tours, architecture, chicago

I'll be in Chicago from July 28 - Aug 3 and I'd like to see the [Chicago Board of Trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Board_of_Trade). According to https://www.architecture.org/experience-caf/tours/detail/chicago-board-of-trade-building/ there's a noon tour on July 12, July 27 and August 9. Unfortunately, I won't be there on those days. Do I have any other options for seeing that building? Are there restaurants or shops inside I could do business at as an excuse to see the interior of that building?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Chicago Architecture Foundation Historic Skyscrapers tour](https://www.architecture.org/experience-caf/tours/detail/historic-skyscrapers/) on dates you'll be there and which includes the Board of Trade Building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few other other Chicago Architecture Foundation tours include the Chicago Board of Trade building, including:

- [Historic Skyscrapers.](https://www.architecture.org/experience-caf/tours/detail/historic-skyscrapers/) Daily, 10 AM & 3:30 PM.
- [Art Deco Skyscrapers:  The Loop.](https://www.architecture.org/experience-caf/tours/detail/art-deco-skyscrapers-the-loop/) August 1, 1:30 PM.

I would call the CAF to ask how much of time each of these tours spends inside the CBOT building, but it seems like these might be adequate substitutes, particularly if you are only interested in the original 1930 building rather than the later additions.